# 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 5356 pos 14: '()

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I get the error

```
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 5356 pos 14: '() {
        // check that it really is our d
```

when I tab on a textview inside my app.

[image: In App error]

This is how i initialize the app itself.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScreenUtilInit(
      designSize: Size(460,790),
      builder: (context) => MultiProvider(
          providers: [
            ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => TestApp()),
            ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => PageControllerProvider()),
            ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => RequestProvider()),
            ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => HistoryProvider()),
            ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => ThemeProvider()),
          ],
          child: App()
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: show us imports

Comment: 'package:flutter/material.dart';
'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';
'package:get/get.dart';
'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
'package:apiella/providers/history_provider.dart';
'package:apiella/providers/page_controller.dart';
'package:apiella/providers/request_provider.dart';
'package:apiella/providers/theme_provider.dart';
'package:apiella/screens/splash_screen.dart';
'package:apiella/providers/testapp.dart';
'package:apiella/utils/colors.dart';
'package:provider/provider.dart';

Comment: looks like very scary issue

Comment: Yeah I don't know what is going wrong.

Comment: The following assertion was thrown building _MediaQueryFromWindow(state: _MediaQueryFromWindowState#16225):
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 5356 pos 14: '() {
        // check that it really is our descendant
        Element? ancestor = dependent._parent;
        while (ancestor != this && ancestor != null)
          ancestor = ancestor._parent;
        return ancestor == this;
      }()': is not true.

Answer (score 0):

try updating flutter_screenutil to version 5.5.2 or higher

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the current version of Flutter (v2.10.2>=),

ScreenUtil package creates a conflict with that version.

If you downgrade your Flutter version back to v.2.10.2, the error will be fixed.

You can access it from this [link](https://vincenttechblog.com/how-to-downgrade-flutter-version-fixed/).